# C# while loop runs inconsistently

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop

I have this code:

```
string winpath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("C:");
int i = 0;

Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to destroy your pc?");

i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int j = 0;

while (j < i)
{
    Process.Start(winpath + @"\Windows\System32\calc.exe");
    j++;
}
```

I want to make the user choose how many calculators to open, I input 1, get one calculator, input 2, I still get one calculator, input 3 and get one calculator, input 5 get 2 calculators. I also tried with a for loop, but with the same results.

Comment: Always use `Path.Combine` to concat your path strings.

Comment: Also, System32 is going to be on the search path, so you only need to `Process.Start("calc.exe")`.

Comment: So what is your actual problem? Your code doesn't match your requirement, but you don't say what is "inconsistent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to add a short delay between starting processes. The while loop runs so quickly that Windows can't respond to the process start requests in time.

Try adding a [`Thread.Sleep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) after each `Process.Start()`.

```
using System.Threading;

for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    Process.Start("calc.exe"); // anything in /system32 is already on the path
    Thread.Sleep(100); // 100 milliseconds
}
```

Comment: This worked, though i used 1000ms delay, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You problem isn't with looping as such, instead you need to calculate the maximum of the loop. 
Looking at your code and based on your description of how many calc instances you want based on the input number, you need to use integer division:

```
i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int j = 0;
while (j < i / 2)
{
    ...
}
```